# Funciones en Kotlin y sus ambientes de aplicación (anko)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

trataré de explicar la situación. Estoy trabajando con Kotlin en Android. Para trabajar con SQlite utilizo "anko", siguiendo este tutorial cree el singleton https://devexperto.com/sqlite-anko-kotlin/

Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema es que en una Activity, y dentro de una AsynckTask necesito crear una tabla. Aquí suceden 2 cosas

1) Si creo la función dentro de la AsyncTask como me dice la ayuda que lo haga, no me reconoce database.use de anko.

2) Si la función de crear la tabla la hago fuera de la AsyncTask me reconoce databse.use pero no puedo referencias la función desde dentro del AsyncTask.

Ejemplo:

Dentro de la clase general

```
class ConfigurationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
```

tengo otra clase con la asynktask .. esto funciona bien

```
class parsearTxtTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean? {
```

en el background de esta clase AsyncTask, necesito crear una función que se llame createTable()

Creandola por fuera de la AsyncTask no la reconoce, no la lee,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En esta imagen pueden visualizar que la función la estoy haciendo por fuera de la AsyncTask y no la está reconociendo, el database.use si, pero la función no.

Si me voy al error que me muestra Android Studio cuando intento referenciar a la función me dice lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciono la segunda opción que es crear la función

Lo hace bien, dentro de la AsyncTask pero me muestra el siguiente error del database.use, cual es la solución?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Perdón si fue muy larga la explicación pero no intenté que se entienda lo mejor posible mi situación.

GRACIAS !!!!

Comment: A ver si entendi. Quieres ejecutar `createTable()` dentro del `AsyncTask`? Por cierto, si publicas la parte del codigo relevante, podrias tener mejores respuestas.

Comment: No salieron las imágenes? allí está el código. Lo que deseo es poder ejecutar la función createTable() dentro o fuera del AsynTask, donde sea lo correcto, pero si la creo dentro no me reconoce database.use de anko, ese es mi problema, como puedo hacer para que me reconozca esa función de anko dentro de una ayncTask

Comment: Por ello en el título puse que creo que es un problema del Ambiente de Aplicación. Según Android Studio la función va dentro del AsyncTask, el problema es que no me reconoce database.use

Comment: @desarollosTELLO, si publicas las imagenes no sera posible copiar el codigo 
 para mejorarlo haciendo mas dificil para los participantes responder. Si quieres respuestas te aconsejo que utilizes el codigo como tal y no imagenes.

Answer (score 0):

No es un error de ambiente ni de android studio. El metodo createTable no estara disponible dentro del task a menos que lo declares [`companion object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html) pero entonces no podras acceder al objecto `database` a menos que tambien lo declares `companion object` tambien.

Tienes que enviar la referencia del objecto database al constructor de la clase `parsearTxTask` y asi podras acceder al metodo `use`:

```
public class parsearTxTask(database : Database) : AsynTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{
  fun onPostExecute(result:Boolean){

      database.use{
        // createTable ..
      }
   }
}
```

Entonces al momento de inicializar el task:

```
new parsearTxTask(database);
```

Pero si necesitas exactamente el metodo `createTable`, pasa la referencia del metodo al constructor del task:

```
public class parsearTxTask(createDelegate : ()-> Unit) : AsynTask<Void,Void,Boolean>
{
  fun onPostExecute(result:Boolean)
  {
    createDelegate();
  }
}
```

Y para utilizarlo seria:

```
parsearTxTask(createTable);
```

Comment: Creo que tengo un problema de contexto

Comment: Estoy tratando de aprender a comenzar con formato